# GWT - Getting UmbrellaException only in the Edge browser

Tags: java, gwt, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on a project with GWT and im still kinda new to it. I was testing my code when i noticed that only in the Edge browser the display was not correct. When looking in the logs i saw a lot of these errors:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: For input string: "176px"
```

So I googled a bit and noticed this post: [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do)

So i tried to add that to my code but that doesnt fix my problem. I am still getting the umbrellaExceptions and the UI is still displayed incorrectly in Edge.

Part of my html file:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="xxxxx.less"/>
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="ie9.less">
<![endif]-->


<title>xxx</title>

<!-- Translations -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="translations/languages.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less-1.7.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxWebApp/xxxWebApp.nocache.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
```

so i tried adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` under the other meta tag. But that doesnt seem to work. I believe i dont added that tag correctly. But i tried different variants like:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8; IE=edge">
```

But still no result. Could somebody how to add that tag correctly or what could cause that UmbrelllaException only in the Edge browser.

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example of a full stacktrace:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: For input string: "176px"
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor24.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.instantiate(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:1110)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:682)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:592)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:149)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:434)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:312)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at com.nedap.retail.rheas.modules.systemconfig.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at com.nedap.retail.rheas.core.webserver.WebServerManager$WebServerHandler.handle(WebServerManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I dont really know what caused the problem, but updating GWT from version 2.8.0 to 2.8.1 solved to problem.

Hope i save some troubles for somone else with this awnser.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on why the error is ONLY on Edge; my impression is that you should be getting it everywhere (or perhaps Edge is less lenient on what seems to be bad input).

However, regarding the error itself:

- Looks like it is caused by the fact that you specify a value in the form "176px" when it should be just "176"; This value can be a width of an element, or a height of an element, or something else; you might get lucky and a simple text search in your project might point to the right place (search by the value "176")
- If the above doesn't work, then you need a better view of the problem; start your dev mode with `-style PRETTY`, and (perhaps recursively) print somewhere the stacktrace of the `UmbrellaException`, and the stack trace of its causes (perhaps using the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663753/turn-a-stack-trace-into-a-string)), using the causes returned by `UmbrellaException#getCauses`.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering. I really think it has something to do with Edge. Because 176px is just another way of representing a distance? Because i have lots of different errors (all with a different px). And also this is accepedt by all other browsers. I do already have the full stacktrace. I will update my original post.

Comment: Two things: You should really go through `UmbrellaException#getCauses` and print stacktraces; UmbrellaException is too general, and with few exceptions, the "real" cause lies in `#getCauses()`.
Second, the error seems to happen server side. Looks like some error was thrown when GWT attempted to instantiate your RPC service.

Comment: Made a mistake; the error seems to be when your RPC request is deserialized, and proper server-side objects get instantiated.
If you have any RPC classes that process/parse stuff in constructor, that's probably where the problem is.
As I've said above, there is a good chance that `#getCauses` shows more info.

Comment: Oke. Will try that. Thank you

Comment: No worries; my best bet right now is that Edge gives you a value in the form "176px", when other browsers gives it to you in the form "176".
You're running a `parseInt` or similar somewhere on the server, in a RPC object, where you expect that value to be a number; therefore you get that error.

Comment: I got to say i cant find that parser on the server side yet. But when i try to get the cause of the exception i get a cause that is null. When i run  public void logClientError(final Throwable exception) {
        if(exception.getCause() == null) {
            LOG.error("cause is null");
        }
        LOG.error("UI error occurred, cause: {}", exception.getCause());
    }

Comment: It's not `getCause` it's `getCauses` (specific to `UmbrellaException`). Which GWT version are you using? I have 2.8.0 and 2.8.1 but perhaps if older, `UmbrellaException` looks different than what I have.

Comment: Also, the code lines referenced by your stacktrace (assuming GWT 2.8.1; but could be good for older versions - RPC hasn't changed that much in a while) are
`parameterValues[i] = streamReader.deserializeValue(parameterTypes[i]`
So chances are that you find the problem by looking at the parameter types of the last RPC call you make before the exception occurs.
              methodParameterTypes[i], resolvedTypes);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145023/discussion-between-rowan-klein-gunnewiek-and-andrei).